# Reduce string matching time in list of string

Tags: python, string, list, memory-management

I have a list of string which has around 100k entry which might increase in future. In case of every input I have to process this list to find exact match.

```
usr_input = "find_word"
check_list = ["first_word", "second_word"] # around 100k entry

# What I am doing right now
if usr_input in check_list:
    print("Found word in list")
```

Now this works fine for smaller dataset. But as size increased to 100k I am seeing it taking a toll on my application. And response time changed to ~1min sometime when we've lot of entry to process.

Is there any way to optimize this operation.

Answer (score 4):

Is using a `set` instead of a `list` an option i.e. is it important if strings appear only once or multiple times? Since it uses hashing, the operation is a lot more efficient.

Comment: To add to that: "A lot more" is O(1) vs O(n) where n = 100k, so the difference is *massive*.